# Git updates in Sandbox Only

Tags: git

I created a website using Jekyll by following instructions here:

https://teddyhyde.com/

Then followed these instructions:

```
curl -u 'username' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"username.github.io"}'
# If you have not yet cloned the repository, do it here, and enter the directory
git clone git@teddyhyde.com:username/username.github.io.git
cd username.github.io
git remote add github git@github.com:username/username.github.io.git
git push -u github master
```

I then make changes locally and push it to git using "git push origin master". However, it gets updated on sandbox:

```
username.github.io.jekyll.teddyhyde.com
```

but not on

```
username.github.io
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to do `git push github master` to update the copy of your repository that's hosted on Github (which is what's published on `username.github.io`)--  `git push origin master` updates the copy hosted at teddyhyde.com, but you have to explicitly specify that you want to push to Github if you want to also publish there (the `origin` remote is automatically configured to be the repository you cloned from when you do a Git clone).